# Update sql table using wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

Am calling an existing wcf service to select records once the record is pulled over thru wcf i do my logic(kinda upload),once its done i have to update the record in the DB.

Here is the way am calling the wcf service

```
 GatewayService.ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient("IService");

        SearchCriteria criteria = new SearchCriteria();
        criteria.UserRoles = new string[]{"*"};


        var stories = proxy.GetStoryItemsByCriteria(criteria);

        var programs = proxy.GetPrograms();

        var readyToDistribute = from story in stories
                                where story.Submitted
                                        && story.Status == "Open"
                                        select story;

        var joined = from story in readyToDistribute
                     join program in programs on story.ProgramId equals program.Id
                     select new StoryProgram(story, program);

        foreach (StoryProgram sp in joined)
        {
            Distribute(sp.Story, sp.Program);
            //update the status here in DB

        }
```

Below is the WCF Service and Controller details

**Below code in the Service**

```
public void UpdateProgram(ProgramData prg)
{
    ServiceController.UpdateProgram(prg);
}
```

**below code in the service Controller**

internal static void UpdateProgram(ProgramData prg)
    {

```
    IProgramDAO prgDAO = DataAccessObjectFactory.GetProgramDAO();
    prgDAO.Update(prg);


}
```

I have the status column in my story table i have to update once the distribute function done.

Any help please.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add an Update method to your WCF service, and call that, with the new data, to update the DB records.

**Upate**

Given your comment, you should be able to do something like this:

```
for each (StoryProgram sp in joined) 
{
    Distribute(sp.Story, sp.Program);             

    // Make any changes you need to sp.Program 

    proxy.UpdateProgram(sp.Program);  
}
```

Comment: its already in my service like        public void UpdateProgram(ProgramData prg)
        {
            ServiceController.UpdateProgram(prg);
        }